# solve three coupled linear partial differential equations with space and time variables using NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, warning-messages

```
Clear[t]
(*define some constants*)
Pr = 0.71;
R = 0.5;
Sc = 0.6;
nn = 0.2;
pde = {[D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] == 
D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + v[x, t] + nn*w[x, t],
3*R*Pr*D[v[x, t], {t, 1}] == (3*R + 4)*D[v[x, t], {x, 2}],
Sc*D[w[x, t], {t, 1}] == D[w[x, t], {x, 2}]]};
ICs = {u[0, t] == 0, v[0, t] == 0, w[0, t] == 0};
BCs = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0, v[0, t] == 0, v[1, t] == 0, 
w[0, t] == 0, w[1, t] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{pde, ICs, BCs}, u[x, t], {t = 0.2}, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[Evaluate [u[x, t] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}]
```

I am unable to plot and getting this error, kindly help me any  one,

> Syntax::sntxf: "{" cannot be followed by
>   "[D[u[x,t],{t,1}]==D[u[x,t],{x,2}]+v[x,t]+nn*w[x,t],3*R*Pr*D[v[x,t],{t,1}]==(3*R+4)*D[v[x,t],{x,2}],Sc*D[w[x,t],{t,1}]==D[w[x,t],{x,2}]]}"

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Have a look [How to | Use Brackets and Braces Correctly](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseBracketsAndBracesCorrectly.html) and check pde and ff there are some more misinterpretations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Clear[t]
(*define some constants*)
Pr = 0.71;
R = 0.5;
Sc = 0.6;
nn = 0.2;
pde = {D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] == 
    D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + v[x, t] + nn*w[x, t], 
   3*R*Pr*D[v[x, t], {t, 1}] == (3*R + 4)*D[v[x, t], {x, 2}], 
   Sc*D[w[x, t], {t, 1}] == D[w[x, t], {x, 2}]};
ICs = {u[x, 0] == x, v[x, 0] == 1 - x, w[x, 0] == 0};
BCs = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 1, v[0, t] == 1, v[1, t] == 0, 
   w[0, t] == 0, w[1, t] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, ICs, BCs}, u, {t, 0, 0.2}, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[sol[x, 0.2], {x, 0, 1}]
```

I changed the initial and boundary conditions a bit to make it more interesting.

Comment: (D[u[x, t], {t, 1}])
this is written in the answer above
what is this command meaning ?