# Solvinh three coupled linear partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

Solve three coupled linear partial differential equations with space and time variables using `NDSolve` and `ParametricPlot`.

```
Clear[t, R, Pr, nn]
(*define some constants*)
Pr = 0.71;
R = 0.5;
t = 0.2;
Sc = 0.6;
nn = 0.2;
pde = {D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] ==
    D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + v[x, t] + nn*w[x, t],
   3*R*Pr*D[v[x, t], {t, 1}] == (3*R + 4)*D[v[x, t], {x, 2}],
   Sc*D[w[x, t], {t, 1}] == D[w[x, t], {x, 2}]};
ICs = {u[x, 0] == x, v[x, 0] == 1 - x, w[x, 0] == 0};
BCs = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 1, v[0, t] : == t, 0 <= t < 1,
   v[0, t] = 1, t > 1, v[1, t] == 0, w[0, t] == 0, w[1, t] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, ICs, BCs}, u, {x, 0, 1}];
a1 = Plot[sol[u, R = 0.2], {x, 0, 1}];
a2 = Plot[sol[u, R = 0.5], {x, 0, 1}];
a3 = Plot[sol[u, R = 0.8], {x, 0, 1}];
a4 = Plot[sol[u, R = 1.2], {x, 0, 1}];
Show[a1, a2, a3, a4, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: It were good if you could explain the difference to your [previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121659/18437) otherwise it looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You have numerous errors. Try the following:

```
Clear[t, R, Pr, nn]
(*define some constants*)
Pr = 0.71;
R = 0.5;

Sc = 0.6;
nn = 0.2;
pde = {D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + v[x, t] + nn*w[x, t], 

   3*R*Pr*D[v[x, t], t] == (3*R + 4)*D[v[x, t], {x, 2}], 
   Sc*D[w[x, t], {t, 1}] == D[w[x, t], {x, 2}]};
ICs = {u[x, 0] == x, v[x, 0] == 1 - x, w[x, 0] == 0};
BCs = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 1, v[0, t] == t, v[1, t] == 0, 
   w[0, t] == 0, w[1, t] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, ICs, BCs}, {u[x, t], w[x, t], v[x, t]}, {x, 
   0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

This will give some solutions. To print them at t=0 try this:
a

```
1 = Plot[sol[[1]] /. t -> 0, {x, 0, 1}];
a2 = Plot[sol[[2]] /. t -> 0, {x, 0, 1}];
a3 = Plot[sol[[3]] /. t -> 0, {x, 0, 1}];

Show[a1, a2, a3, PlotRange -> All]
```

yielding the following

[image]
The boundary condition cannot be fixed as you did it: `v[0, t] : == t, 0 <= t < 1, v[0, t] = 1, t > 1` Instead try the following:

```
 BCs1 = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 1, v[0, t] == If[0 <= t < 1, t, 1], 
   v[1, t] == 0, w[0, t] == 0, w[1, t] == 0};
```

Finally, the construct like `Plot[sol[u, R = 0.2], {x, 0, 1}]`has no sense. To plot the solution at different values of R you need to first solve your equation at these values, and only then to plot the solutions. You may do it as follows:

```
ClearAll[sol2, t, R, Pr, nn]
(*define some constants*)
Pr = 0.71;
Sc = 0.6;
nn = 0.2;
pde2[R_] := {D[u[x, t], t] == 
    D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + v[x, t] + nn*w[x, t], 
   3*R*Pr*D[v[x, t], t] == (3*R + 4)*D[v[x, t], {x, 2}], 
   Sc*D[w[x, t], {t, 1}] == D[w[x, t], {x, 2}]};
ICs = {u[x, 0] == x, v[x, 0] == 1 - x, w[x, 0] == 0};
BCs = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 1, v[0, t] == t, v[1, t] == 0, 
   w[0, t] == 0, w[1, t] == 0};
sol2[R_] := 
 NDSolveValue[{pde2[R], ICs, BCs1}, {u[x, t], w[x, t], v[x, t]}, {x, 
   0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
BCs1 = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 1, v[0, t] == If[0 <= t < 1, t, 1], 
   v[1, t] == 0, w[0, t] == 0, w[1, t] == 0};
```

and then print, say, for R=0.5 and t=0.7

```
a1 = Plot[Evaluate[sol2[0.5][[1]] /. t -> 0.7], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Finally, the boundary condition `u[0, t] == 0` and the initial one `u[x, 0] == x` are inconsistent. But this is up to you.

Have fun!